# Implementing a Yearmonth class

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime, c++14

Recently I wrote a program that was required to handle year and month data and so I wrote this class to encapsulate that handling.  What I needed was a way to initialize the `Yearmonth` object based on the current local time, and allow a simple method of calculating future `Yearmonth` values based on a duration in months.  This sample code illustrates how I use it:

## ymtest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Yearmonth.h"

int main()
{
    YM::Yearmonth ym;    // today
    std::cout << ym << '\n';
    ym += 2;         // 2 months from now
    std::cout << ym << '\n';
    ym += 14;        // test year increment
    std::cout << ym << '\n';
}
```

## Yearmonth.h

```
#ifndef YEARMONTH_H
#define YEARMONTH_H
#include <iostream>

namespace YM {
class Yearmonth
{
public:
    // construct with today's year and month
    Yearmonth();
    // construct with year, month (1=Jan, 12=Dec)
    Yearmonth(unsigned ayear, unsigned amonth);
    // increment by given number of months
    Yearmonth &operator+=(const unsigned mon);
    // return year
    unsigned year() const;
    // return month (1=Jan, 12=Dec)
    unsigned month() const;
    // prints to ostream.  E.g. 2014 Dec ==> "201412"
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Yearmonth &ym);
private:
    unsigned myyear;
    unsigned mymonth;
};
}
#endif //YEARMONTH_H
```

## Yearmonth.cpp

```
#include <ctime>
#include "Yearmonth.h"

namespace YM {
Yearmonth::Yearmonth()
{
    time_t tt;
    time(&tt);
    tm *t = localtime(&tt);
    myyear = t->tm_year + 1900;
    mymonth = t->tm_mon;
}

Yearmonth::Yearmonth(unsigned ayear, unsigned amonth)
    : myyear(ayear), mymonth(amonth-1)
{
    myyear += mymonth/12;
    mymonth %= 12;
}

unsigned Yearmonth::year() const
{
    return myyear;
}

unsigned Yearmonth::month() const
{
    return mymonth+1;
}

Yearmonth &Yearmonth::operator+=(const unsigned mon)
{
    mymonth += mon;
    myyear += mymonth/12;
    mymonth %= 12;
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Yearmonth &ym)
{
    return out << ym.myyear * 100 + ym.mymonth+1;
}
}
```

The class seems sufficient for my needs and everything works.  Have I missed anything important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only have a few small remarks to make:

- In your header file, don't include `<iostream>`: include `<iosfwd>` instead which contains the forward declarations for every type in `<iostream>`.
- Also, you only use `std::ostream` in your source file, so you could simply include `<ostream>` there.
- Several times, you compute `mymonth / 12` and `mymonth % 12`. If your class is designed to be used intensively, you could consider using `std::div(mymonth, 12)` which will compute both values at once and may therefore be slightly faster (if you really need it).
- You may want to prefix `time_t`, `time`, `tm` and `localtime` with `std::`. Them coming from the C standard library doesn't prevent you to use `std::`.
- Using a `const unsigned` parameter seems pretty useless. I don't have strong opinions on the `const` on value parameters, but you could safely drop it since it adds little value.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider your class to be good, but the most complex part of your code is the math of adding months to it. You are already doing modulo-arithmetic in the default constructor, so I would just make your underlying unit a single `unsigned` value.... which is a literal `year * 12 + month` value. This makes any arithmetic easy, and the presentation of the values is easy too. It also saves an unsigned value of space in memory.... note that there is no year 0.... and also that it is now limited to the year 5K or so, on 16-bit-int machines.

The cost of the modulo will be low on the get-methods, and I doubt it would be a significant part of any performance issues.

In other words, I would define the class as having the single `unsigned myyearmonth;` and then implement the class as:

```
Yearmonth::Yearmonth()
{
    time_t tt;
    time(&tt);
    tm *t = localtime(&tt);
    unsigned year = t->tm_year + 1900;
    unsigned month = t->tm_mon;
    myyearmonth = year * 12 + month;
}

Yearmonth::Yearmonth(unsigned ayear, unsigned amonth)
{
    myyearmonth = ayear * 12 + amonth - 1;
}

unsigned Yearmonth::year() const
{
    return myyearmonth / 12;
}

unsigned Yearmonth::month() const
{
    return (myyearmonth % 12) + 1;
}

Yearmonth &Yearmonth::operator+=(const unsigned mon)
{
    myyearmonth += mon;
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Yearmonth &ym)
{
    return out << ym.year() * 100 + ym.month();
}
```

Comment: `amonth` in the constructor is 0-based, but `Yearmonth::month()` returns 1-based values?

Comment: @200_success - yeah the `amonth` would be input as 1-based, agreed, so the constructor should reduce that to a 0-based month, which I have now edited it to do.